# dropdown list is not enabling on change of another dropdown list for first time using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using two dropdown lists in my asp.net page.. In that I want to change ddl2 based on the value of ddl1.. My design coding is given below..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"  Width="158px" TabIndex="1">
    <asp:ListItem value="0">Please select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="1">one</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="3">three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"  Width="158px" TabIndex="1">
    <asp:ListItem value="1">one selected</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">two selected</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="3">three selected</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I wrote code in javascript, that based on ddl1 value, ddl2 value has to be changed.. Initially on page load ddl2 is disabled.. After changing ddl1 only ddl2 will be enabled and change according to ddl1..

```
$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %>').change(function() {  

 var val =$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
 if (val == "0")
 {              
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);   
 }
 else
 {   
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false);              
 }
);
```

My problem is, after page loaded, when I change ddl1 for first item, ddl2 is not enabling.. After changing ddl1, then only ddl2 is enabling and its value changing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %>').on('change',function() {  

 var val =$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
 if (val == "0")
 {              
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);   
 }
 else
 {   
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false);              
 }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPZU/7/)

Answer (score 0):

What I can see on the first eye - you've lost one `}` in your javascript:
try this:

```
$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %>').change(function() {  

 var val =$('#<%=ddl1.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
 if (val == "0")
 {              
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);   
 }
 else
 {   
   $('#<%=ddl2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false);              
 }
} // it was lost
);
```

and also use not `true` and `false`, but `disabled="disabled"` to get control disabled

Comment: In my coding, its available.. But while aligning here, I accidentally erased